# PHP Laravel back роут

Tags: php, laravel

После авторизации если нажать возврат редиректит на /home. Почему?

Comment: потому что если вы авторизованы, то с /login редиректит на /home

Answer (score 1):

Это стандартное поведение Laravel. Поменять можно в LoginController:

```
protected $redirectTo;

public function __construct()
{        
    $this->redirectTo = route('index');//Указать куда редиректить
}
```

Comment: всеравно редиректит на /home

Answer (score 0):

redirectTo может быть методом

```
protected function redirectTo()
{        
    return route('route-name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть посредник App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated. В его методе handle можно указать, куда будет перенаправляться аутентифицированный пользователь вместо страниц